# Alternative to using mechanize to fetch data?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, developer-tools, mechanize-python

Currently, I am using `mechanize` to fill up a form and send a POST request, then I am doing a `regex` search on the response to get the data ( a floating point number).

Is there any way I can do this by just sending a POST request? I know this is possible by using a combination of any browser's Developer Tools and the `requests` module to send the request but I have failed to find a comprehensive tutorial. I would also like some details about the steps involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First step: get the field name

Inspect the HTML code and find the `name` attribute of the field. For example, the comment form on this page is (in Chrome, right-click and choose "inspect element"):

```html
<textarea name="comment" cols="68" rows="3" 
placeholder="Use comments to ask for more information or 
suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."
></textarea>
```

The field name is `comment`.

### Step 2: assemble a dict of `name: value` for each field (including the hidden inputs)

Lets call it data:

```python
data = {
   "comment": "this is a comment",
   "post_id": 1234
}
```

### Step 3: use the `data` argument of `requests.post'

```python
response = requests.post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
```

### More advanced stuff

If your form has `file` fields you may have to check "[More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)" in the docs. Same goes for [custom authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication), [cookie handling](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies), etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the key values in `data` enclosed within double quotes?

Comment: Also, I have 2 urls, the url in which the form contains, and another page that get's displayed after the POST request, which request should I include here?

Comment: Yes, damn JavaScript habits! The URL is the one from the form's action attribute or the page URL if the form lacks this attribute (respectively your URL #2 and #1 I guess).

Comment: I did the above mentioned steps, but I am failing to get the response. It just returns the page with the form and an additional error message ( within the html). I think I am passing the data right, but I was reading on `requests` a bit and learnt about headers...are they important? How would I define them for my usecase?

Comment: Ah! I found it! This is making a POST request, so it should be `requests.post(....)`. Totally missed that.

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed. I also don't know how I could write `requests.post` in the text and `requests.get` on the code sample.